# C# - How to convert string date to DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string date

```
"7.08.2014"
```

and want to convert into this format :

```
2014-07-08
```

I tried a no of solution that previously propoed on stackoverflow, unfortunately none of work for me. Any suggestion please, here is my code

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(match.date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It keep throws an error

```
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: Is there some reason, like validity checking, that makes you want to use DateTime? They way you've posed your question (first 4 lines) it could be considered a simple string transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong format. Try this:

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(match.date, "d.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`DateTime.ParseExact` attempts to convert a string representation of a datetime to a `DateTime` by using the format provided in the second parameter.

To obtain a string in the other format you have to call `ToString` on `parsedDate` with a custom format specifier:

```
var dateInCustomFormat = parsedDate.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Rather "d.MM.yyyy" because of single `7` without leading `0`.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: Indeed. Updated.

Comment: Great that works, But how do I convert back into my required format? 2014-07-08

Comment: @user3398887: Now you have a DateTime. YOu can use ToString with a custom format specifier. Give me a second.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work when I am trying to save in a db, because my model property has DateTime format but the above will again parse them into string. Any suggestion, please

Comment: @user3398887: If you have a DateTime in the model then just pass parsedDate. If you need to display it somewhere in the other format you mentioned then that's a whole other issue as it depends on the app you have (you can create a new question about that if you can't find the answer here).

Comment: Agreed, Thank you very much. I will accept answer in 2 minutes